# Como assinar PDF com certificado digital A3 em C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, certificado-digital

Preciso assinar um arquivo PDF com certificado digital A3.

Pode ser em C# ou VB.NET.

Comment: https://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2010/07/assinando-digitalmente-um-xml-usando-c/